# not getting variable's values inside the isql command

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Below I am trying to automate the Sybase reporting job but unable to get the variable value as sp_helpdb proc's parameter.

```
#!/bin/sh

. ./SYBASE.sh

dblist=`isql -S syb157134 -Usa -b -P << endit 
use master
go
set nocount on
go
select name
from sysdatabases
go
exit
endit
`

for db in $dblist
do
        if [ -n "$dblist" ]; then
                `isql -S syb157134 -Usa -b -P <<EOF > /sybase/pankaj/INPUT/sp_helpdb_$db.txt
                use master
                go        
                sp_helpdb "$db"   ------not able to get the $db variable value
                go              
                exit
                endit
                EOF  
                `  

        else
                echo "Array empty"
fi

done
```

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

Variables in quotes are not expanded inside a heredoc. You should remove the double quotes from `"$db"`